# How can I return a response in ASP.NET Core MVC middleware using MVC's content negotiation?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware, asp.net-core-2.0

I have some ASP.NET Core MVC middleware to catch unhandled exceptions that I would like to return a response from.

While it is easy to just `httpContext.Response.WriteAsync` to write a string and e.g. use `JsonSerializer` to serialise an object to a string, I would like to use the standard serialisation settings and content negotiation so that if I change my default output formatting to XML or a `text/xml` accept header is sent when I have multiple output formatters configured then XML is returned, as it does if I return an `ObjectResult` from a controller.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved in middleware?

Here is my code so far which only writes JSON:

```
public class UnhandledExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IOutputFormatter _outputFormatter;
    private readonly IHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory _streamWriterFactory;

    public UnhandledExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, JsonOutputFormatter outputFormatter, IHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory streamWriterFactory)
    {
        _next = next;
        _outputFormatter = outputFormatter;
        _streamWriterFactory = streamWriterFactory;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        var error = new ErrorResultModel("Internal Server Error", exception.Message, exception.StackTrace);
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        await _outputFormatter.WriteAsync(new OutputFormatterWriteContext(context, _streamWriterFactory.CreateWriter, typeof(ErrorResultModel), error));
    }
}
```

where `ErrorResultModel` is defined as:

```
public class ErrorResultModel
{
    public string ResultMessage { get; };
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; };
    public string ExceptionStackTrace { get; };

    public ErrorResultModel(string resultMessage, string exceptionMessage, string exceptionStackTrace)
    {
        ResultMessage = resultMessage;
        ExceptionMessage = exceptionMessage;
        ExceptionStackTrace = exceptionStackTrace;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible in [ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7238#issuecomment-357265641).

This will be possible [in 2.1](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7238#issuecomment-357391426):

```cs
    public static class HttpContextExtensions
    {
        private static readonly RouteData EmptyRouteData = new RouteData();
    
        private static readonly ActionDescriptor EmptyActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();
    
        public static Task WriteResultAsync<TResult>(this HttpContext context, TResult result)
            where TResult : IActionResult
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }
    
            var executor = context.RequestServices.GetService<IActionResultExecutor<TResult>>();
    
            if (executor == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"No result executor for '{typeof(TResult).FullName}' has been registered.");
            }
    
            var routeData = context.GetRouteData() ?? EmptyRouteData;
    
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(context, routeData, EmptyActionDescriptor);
    
            return executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, result);
        }
    }

    public class Program : StartupBase
    {
        public static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            return BuildWebHost(args).RunAsync();
        }
    
        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            return new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Program>().UseKestrel().Build();
        }
    
        public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters();
        }
    
        public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.Use((ctx, next) =>
            {
                var model = new Person("Krisian", "Hellang");
    
                var result = new ObjectResult(model);
    
                return ctx.WriteResultAsync(result);
            });
        }
    }
    
    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }
    
        public string FirstName { get; }
    
        public string LastName { get; }
    }
```

Comment: Any idea why `var executor = context.RequestServices.GetService<IActionResultExecutor<TResult>>();` this code fails? I've tried all variations, including resolving just ObjectResultExecutor. Nothing works. But I can see it registered after `services.AddMvc()`.